# What is the difference between runOnUiThread method and Handler? Which one is the best to use?

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

I usually use the method

```
 runOnUiThread (new Runnable () {

     @Override
     public void run () {

     }

 });
```

to launch some prcess in the main thread. just recently I discovered this one

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable () {

    @Override
    public void run () {
        // this will run in the main thread
    }

});
```

My question is what is the difference between the two methods and which one is the best to use?

Comment: see `Activity#runOnUiThread` method implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are actually same. Both `runOnUiThread` and `Handler#post` runs the passed `Runnable` in the UI Thread.

FYI, you can also execute any `Runnable` on UI Thread with the help of any `View` by calling the method `View#post(runnable)`.

Since all approaches uses `Handler` internally, all are same and there won't be any difference in using any of these.

Comment: With `handler.post()` method you can set delay.

Comment: @kfir88 there is no best, `runOnUiThread` also uses `Handler` internally. You can use any approach.

Comment: @OmidNejadabbasi, for delay one can use `Handler#postDelayed()` or `View#postDelayed()`

Comment: @NabinBhandari  Thanks☻